# Pagination not working

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am using the following code for pagination but its not working .Please help me out and tell that what is it that i am doing wrong

```
  <div class="isotope"> 
               <?php $paged= (get_query_var('paged' )) ? get_query_var('paged'):1; ?>
               <?php $args = array( 'post_type'=>'events',
                             'posts_per_page' => 2 ,
                             'paged'=>$paged
                           );              
              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
              if($loop->have_posts()):while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();   
              $count=0;
        ?>          
            <div class="row event-list  my-events <?php echo $type[0]->name; ?> ">            
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 paddingdel-l">
                  <h5><?php the_title( ); ?></h5>
                    <div class="row">                             
                      <div class="co-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6 event-list-right">                          
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 paddingdel-l pad0">
                              <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/share.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                            </div>
                          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 social">                     
                          <?php get_sidebar('share'); ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>                   
                </div>                
            </div>    
            <?php  endwhile; ?>           
            <?php endif; ?>                
                  <div class="row">
                    <p class="pull-left" ><?php previous_posts_link( '&larr; Newer posts' ); ?></p>
                    <p class="pull-right" ><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts &rarr; ' ); ?></p>
                 </div>        
        </div>
```

Comment: review http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query

Comment: i reviewd codex, tried every thing , disabled all the plugin but still was not able to make pagination work

Comment: please explain in detail what 'is not working' exactly means. have you tried to use per Codex `previous_posts_link( '&larr; Newer posts', $loop->max_num_pages )`

Comment: Thanks Michael , i was not using $loop->max_num_pages

Comment: good that you got it fixed - I'll post this as an answer for you to accept, so the forum can be kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use per [the quoted Codex chapter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query) for example:

`next_posts_link( 'Older posts &rarr; ', $loop->max_num_pages )`

and also:

`previous_posts_link( '&larr; Newer posts', $loop->max_num_pages )`

Comment: Michael, I think you got mixed up here :-). Should be `next_posts_link`, not `previous_posts_link`. You linked to the correct page though

Comment: should be both - I got mixed up with 'next' and 'prev'; I'll correct this in my answer.